# RDP from Windows 10 to Ubuntu via XRDP

Tags: networking, permissions, remote-desktop

**Using Ubuntu 19.04**

I am successful in getting logged in and all is well with how the interface is working. However, I have some quirky issues that I hope someone can help me resolve.

My main issue is: When I click on apps some are failing due to lack of permissions. Some work without a hitch though. Apparently, a new session is spawned when I connect but the permission level is hindered.

Even though my login account is admin, it does not fully work as admin when remotely logged in. I'm on a local network, not through the internet. I would like to have Admin access just as if I were logging in locally to the PC.

Can someone guide me to a solution?

Comment: Are you connecting with Xorg? After login, did you pass the blank/black screen?

Comment: Yes; I followed the instruction provided by Griffton here: http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13588

Comment: I have the app I wanted to get working via RDP working now. However there is still an issue of permissions. My account which is in the admin group still does not have the same permissions In a an RDP session that it does  in a local login. For example: I can't install additional software without using sudo in a terminal to do it. The gnome-software app will not do it.

Comment: I get the error code: "Unable to Download Updates: You do not have permission to install software". However, using terminal and issuing sudo gnome-software works.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a recurring (and random issue). Polkit might be blocking software installation through remote session....  To overcome this limitation, you have to

> **option 1** - perform installation from command line using sudo command (ex; sudo apt-get install tweaks
>
> **option 2** - from a terminal session, type sudo gnome-software....

This will start software center with admin rights and you should be able to perform the installation

hope this help

till next time